# Batch:How to return the contents of a txt file from a finstr command

Tags: batch-file, findstr

Im trying to figure out how to search a folder with all of its subfolders for a file containing a keyword than return it's contents as a string. So far it searches a folder and its subfolders and can find the file but i can't figure out how to do the last part.

```
for /R %test% %%F IN (*) DO (

    echo %%F | finstr "hi"

)
```

Edit: it searches for a filename not it's contents

Comment: pipe each filepath/filename to a `cat`

Comment: Are you wanting to return the line content containing the matched string? or the entire file content if it contains the matched string?

Comment: The entire file content

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example which may help you out

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "baseDir=C:\Users\Guld3rp"
Set "fileExt=txt"
Set "srcWord=hi"
For /F "Delims=" %%A In (
    'FindStr/SRMIC:"\<%srcWord%\>" "%baseDir%\*.%fileExt%" 2^>Nul'
) Do Type "%%A"
Pause
```

*Just change as necessary the values in lines 2-4 to test it.*